# Why setOnCompletionListener is being called only once?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am making a music application like to enhance my skills and I want it to autoplay songs using `setOnCompletionListener` method. But it only run once, song1 into song2 and then it won't go to song3.

I put the `setOnCompletionListener` on my `onCreate` method like this:

```
mySong.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        nextSong();
    }
});
```

This is my `nextSong()` method:

```
public void nextSong() {
    ifPlaying = true; //for displaying purposes
    displayPP();     //for displaying purposes

    //if switch is checked, randomize songs
    if (mySwitch.isChecked()) {
        musicCounter = dice.nextInt(songNumbers);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(musicCounter), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mySong.reset();
        playMusic();
    } else {
        if (musicCounter < songNumbers - 1) {
            musicCounter++;
            mySong.reset();
            playMusic();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more songs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("Jason Mraz")) {
            displaySong(jm);
        } else if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("fob")) {
            displaySong(fob);
        } else if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
            displaySong(ed);
        }
    }
}
```

The playMusic method in case you wonder:

```
public void playMusic() {

    //test is intent.putExtra to know what index was clicked on my listview

    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("Jason Mraz")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, jm[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(jm);
        songNumbers = jm.length;
        mySong.start();

    } else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("fob")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, fob[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(fob);
        songNumbers = fob.length;
        mySong.start();
    } else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, ed[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(ed);
        songNumbers = ed.length;
        mySong.start();
    }
}
```

And also, I've been using the nextSong(); method on my next button and it is working just fine. So I wonder why it is only being performed once inside setOnCompletionListener(); method. This is my the code for my next button:

```
public void nextClicked(View view) {
    nextSong();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are only setting `onCompletionListener` once, then, whenever you invoke `playMusic()`, you override `mySong` value and you never set `onCompletionListener` again.

One way to fix your problem is to modify `playMusic()` method as follows:

```
public void playMusic() {
    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("Jason Mraz")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, jm[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(jm);
        songNumbers = jm.length;
    }else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("fob")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, fob[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(fob);
        songNumbers = fob.length;
    }else if(test.equalsIgnoreCase("ed")) {
        mySong = MediaPlayer.create(MusicClass.this, ed[musicCounter]);
        displaySong(ed);
        songNumbers = ed.length;
    }
    mySong.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
           nextSong();
        }
    });
    mySong.start();
}
```